# Linq query to get large set of data where user in list of userID

Tags: c#, linq, query-optimization

Can you please help fix this query.

```
                        var currentHiddenWorkshopIds = Uow.UserCompetencyPlans
                       .Where(ucp => ucp.UserId == userId && ucp.CompetencyPlan.Hidden)
                       .SelectMany(ucp => ucp.CompetencyPlan.CompetencyPlanCourses)
                       .Where(cpc => cpc.Course.Hidden)
                       .SelectMany(cpc => cpc.Course.CourseWorkshops)
                       .Select(cw => cw.WorkshopId)
                       .ToList();
```

currently this is inside a for loop where I am looping through all users in a list of string

my hope is to rewrite this query so I get back "WorkshopID" and userId in a dictionary.
key being user id while the value being a list of "WorkshopID"

how can I do that?
I tried to start with something like this but getting stuck on "selectMany(ucp => ucp.Com...)
My hope is to execute this query once outside the for loop and store it in dictionary object. Then inside for loop, I can look at the dictionary to get the value instead of hitting the database.

```
            var currentHiddenWorkshopIds =
from ucp in Uow.UserCompetencyPlans.Where(a => a.CompetencyPlan.Hidden).AsQueryable()
join u in userIds
on ucp.UserId equals u

select ucp;
```

Can you please help? Thanks so much!